What does sigma mean in scipy.optimize.curve_fit?
Assume that I have a very simple model that measures some quantity by repetitive sampling. As I understood from statistics, there's the error of mean which can be computed as
$u = \frac{\hat\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$
where $\hat\sigma = \frac{\sum(x-\bar{x})}{\sqrt{n-1}}$
This uncertainty will vanish as the sampling $n \rightarrow \infty$, however there's still the uncertainty due to the instrument itself (type B uncertainty). Usually one assume that the two can be added up quadratically.
What if this is done through a curve fit? I was trying to do something like this

This could be easily done by scipy.optimize.curve_fit:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_length = 10000
x = np.array(range(data_length))
y = 5 * np.ones(data_length) + np.random.normal(0, 1, data_length)
u_y = 1 * np.ones(data_length)


def func(x, b):
    return  x*0 + b

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x,y, sigma=u_y, absolute_sigma=False)

# generate the plot
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=u_y, fmt='o')
plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'r-')
plt.show()

print(popt)
print(np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)))

As it turn out the error $\rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$, hence this means there is some way to beat the instrument precision by performing hugh number of measurments, which sounds completely unrealistic. Additionally I find that if I scale sigma by sigma=1e6*u_y , the error of popt is not affected, which means the sigma in this function does not operate as something corresponds to uncertainty of a measurment given by instrument.
I looked up the documentation and find that I should set absolute_sigma=True. I tried but it seems to always return 1/np.sqrt(data_length), and the randomness of the dataset itself plays no role. Additionaly the fact that this error also vanish at $n \rightarrow \infty$ is continuing to worry me.
what is the right way to include the error of instrument in a curve fit? What does the sigma here really stand for? How to include this term in real curve fit where you have multiple parameters? I have tried a linear problem
sampling_points = int(1e2)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, sampling_points)
y = 5 * x + np.random.normal(0, 1, sampling_points)
u_y = 1 * np.ones(sampling_points)


def func(x, a, b):
    return  x*a + b

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x,y, sigma=1*u_y, absolute_sigma=False)

print("sample points: ", sampling_points)
print("k={pop[0]:.2f}, b={pop[1]:.2f}".format(pop=popt))
print("error of k: ", np.sqrt(pcov[0,0]))
print("error of b: ", np.sqrt(pcov[1,1]))

and it still turns out that you can kill completely your error by increasing data point
sample points:  100
k=4.74, b=0.23
error of k:  0.37312467183800596
error of b:  0.2159669523150594

and
sample points:  1000000
k=5.01, b=-0.00
error of k:  0.0034627280798220374
error of b:  0.0019992075688566534


Hello and welcome, great question! Can you post the equations as images? SO sadly does not support tex

Scipy's curve fit implements a non linear least squares fit. The sigma here represents the uncertainty in the y direction. By default the X² is calculated as:
chi_sqrd = np.sum((y - f(x, *theta))**2 / sigma**2)

The covariance matrix and thus parameter error is calculated as the inverse of the hessian matrix. This is proportional to 1/sqrt(n). If sigma = True the error is carried through to the hessian. (The docs don't really specify what this is supposed to mean). Neither is "correct". This is a matter of judgement.
This is the expected result. More data gives us a better estimation of the "True" value, however with diminishing returns, because you have a higher resolution on your probability distribution. With enough runs you can absolutely achieve a higher accuracy than with a single measurement. That is the whole point of doing multiple measurements.
To include instrumental uncertainty the total uncertainty for each point should combine both the random noise in the data (Type A uncertainty, e.g., σ_random​) and the instrumental uncertainty (Type B uncertainty, e.g., σ_instrument​). If you have systemic errors you should include them as a fitted parameter. Smart experiment design accounts for the possible biases.
Note that least squares is not the only way to fit a curve and each method yields different errors because the optimization functions are differently curved in parameter space. (Compare for example MLE)
